# Injecting a single Spring bean instance into a static variable of a utility class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, vaadin, static-methods

I have this web application built with Spring and Vaadin, in which I wanted to do this, for the sake of convenience:

Create a utility class that wraps a Spring service, and allows the use of its static methods throughout the application, without having to worry about injecting this service everywhere, like so:

```
String configurationValue = ConfigurationUtil.getString("some.property.key");
```

If you work with Vaadin, you might see how convenient this is, because the whole presentation layer is written in Java and you can't always inject Spring services into your Vaadin components as these Vaadin components are not always Spring components themselves.

So this is my utility class:

```
public final class ConfigurationUtil {

    // this is the spring service:
    private static ConfigurationService configurationService;

    public static void setConfigurationService(final ConfigurationService configurationService) {
        ConfigurationUtil.configurationService = configurationService;
    }

    public static String getString(final String key) {
        return configurationService.getString(key);
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service("configurationService")
public class ConfigurationServiceImpl implements ConfigurationService, BeanFactoryAware {

    private final FrameworkService frameworkService;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigurationServiceImpl(final FrameworkService frameworkService) throws IOException, ConfigurationException {
        
        // this is where I set this service bean to the utility class
        ConfigurationUtil.setConfigurationService(this);

        this.frameworkService = frameworkService;
    }

    public String getString(String key)  {
        // code that retrieves a configuration value from our configuration files
    }

}
```

My question here is: I'm a bit worried about this causing a bottleneck to access the configuration service, as multiple threads will be calling it, from multiple user sessions. Would this be a problem? Please explain why. Also, feel free to point out other problems with this solution.

Comment: There isn't. But should you do it like this probably not. Inject the dependencies or pass them around, using static methods for this/like this is generally an anti-pattern.

Comment: @M.Deinum True, it IS a bit weird. Thanks for your 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a bean that implements ApplicationContextAware like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
        context = ac;
    }

    public static String getString(final String key) {
        ConfigurationService configurationService = context.getBean(ConfigurationService.class);
        return configurationService.getString(key);
    }

    public static <T> T bean(Class<T> beanType) {
        return context.getBean(beanType);
    }

}
```

You can create a method like in the example to give static access to Spring Beans or what you requested to get a String from your ConfigurationService.

Btw. I use this a lot in Vaadin applications because I don't want to make every component a Spring Bean.

Comment: Thank you for all the trouble you took, but my question was: will my solution cause a bottleneck? Or do you see any other problem with that solution. If there are no problems, I'm perfectly fine with it.

Comment: From a framework point of view not. It depends what your config service does  in getString